# How do I check if my program is ran by user as administrator (Vista/Win7, C++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, uac, administrator

I saw IsInRole method but I can't find information on how to use it with C++.

Answer (score 2):

There's a C++ code snippet in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220213/c-detect-if-running-with-elevated-privileges/1220234#1220234) taken from the [UACHelpers](http://uachelpers.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

Answer (score 2):

This code solves your problem. Feel free to use it. It works with SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY.

```
/**
  IsGroupMember determines if the current thread or process has a token that contais a given and enabled user group. 

  Parameters
   dwRelativeID: Defines a relative ID (par of a SID) of a user group (e.g. Administrators DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS (544) = S-1-5-32-544)
   bProcessRelative: Defines whether to use the process token (TRUE) instead of the thread token (FALSE). If FALSE and no thread token is present
     the process token will be used though.
   bIsMember: Returns the result of the function. The value returns TRUE if the user is an enabled member of the group; otherwise FALSE.

  Return Value
    If the function succeeds, the return value is TRUE; otherwise FALSE. Call GetLastError for more information.
*/
BOOL IsGroupMember(DWORD dwRelativeID, BOOL bProcessRelative, BOOL* pIsMember)
{
    HANDLE hToken, hDupToken;
    PSID pSid = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SidAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    if (!pIsMember)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (bProcessRelative || !OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, TRUE, &hToken))
    {
        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (!DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityIdentification, &hDupToken))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    hToken = hDupToken;

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SidAuthority, 2,
            SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, dwRelativeID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            &pSid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!CheckTokenMembership(hToken, pSid, pIsMember))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        FreeSid(pSid);

        *pIsMember = FALSE;
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    FreeSid(pSid);

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL IsUserAdministrator(BOOL* pIsAdmin)
{
    return IsGroupMember(DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, FALSE, pIsAdmin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`IsUSerAnAdmin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463.aspx) explains that it's deprecated since Vista, but points you to [`CheckTokenMembership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389.aspx). That should do the job for you.

Answer (score -1):

You might try this piece of code. It gives a sketch of what needs to be done:

```
const HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
if (hProcess==NULL)
    return FAILURE;

HANDLE hToken;
const BOOL lR = OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
if (lR == NULL) 
    return FAILURE;

PSID psidAdministrators;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY x = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &x, 2, 
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &psidAdministrators))
    return FAILURE;

bool isAdmin = false; //dummy init
DWORD size;
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenGroups, NULL, 0, &size);
char* buffer = new char[size]; 
DWORD notUsed;
if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenGroups, (void*)buffer, size, &notUsed))
    return FAILURE;

TOKEN_GROUPS* ptgGroups = (TOKEN_GROUPS*)buffer;
isAdmin = false; //until proven otherwise
for (UINT32 i=0; i<ptgGroups->GroupCount; ++i)
{
    if (EqualSid(psidAdministrators, ptgGroups->Groups[i].Sid))
    {
        isAdmin = true;
        break;
    }
}

FreeSid(psidAdministrators);
return isAdmin;
```

Comment: This code is the NT4 way to check if a SID is part of a users token, it does not work correctly on newer systems and should not be used. See Rup's SO link for my answer and which function to call...

Comment: @Anders: It works on Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7 for sure. This code was tested rather extensively on these three systems. Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: I KNOW its broken, so you just did not test properly. There is a thing called a deny-only SID and your current code does not handle those, you are supposed to use CheckTokenMembership.

Comment: -1: Yes, this code is broken since Windows 2000 and the introduction of so called restricted tokens. (check MSDN: CreateRestrictedToken). A token has a list of group memberships. Every token group has also a flag variable that may contain SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY. If this flag is set for a group Windows will use the group for access checking only for DENY access control elements (ACEs). So an admin group membership with SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY won't be able to access any resource with allow ACE. The solution is to check for this flag in your code in addition, or use CheckTokenMembership.