# C#: detecting if running as super user, both in Windows and Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

this question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220213/c-detect-if-running-with-elevated-privileges). I want to detect if my program is being run either with privilege elevation in Winows through UAC, or as **root** in Unix/Mono.

How can I do that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the function below would take care of the Unix/Mono end of the question.  Btw, I didn't actually compile or run this, but you get the idea.

```
private bool AmIRoot()
{
   //Declarations:
   string fileName = "blah.txt",
          content = "";

   //Execute shell command:
   System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   proc.EnableRaisingEvents=false; 
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = "whoami > " + fileName;
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
   proc.Start();
   proc.WaitForExit();

   //View results of command execution:
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
   content = sr.ReadLine();
   sr.Close();

   //Clean up magic file:
   File.Delete(fileName);

   //Return to caller:
   if(content == "root")
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Yea, maybe merging the two approaches succeeds... I might also run whoami from Process.Start and read it's standard output

Comment: why not System.Environment.UserName == "root" ?