# Get the rights for current user

Tags: windows, permissions

Hello I am working in VB.Net 2010 framework 2.0.
In my application I want to run a Setup.exe with Process.start.
I want to know that whether the user who has started the my application is having the rights to run the setup.exe
Thanks for any reply in advance.

Comment: I added a "windows" tag to your question, as otherwise it wasn't clear which operating system you were addressing.

Comment: The [`IsUserAnAdmin` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463.aspx) is by far the easiest way of doing this, but you'll have to P/Invoke to get at it. I don't know what the .NET Framework offers it; I wrapped `IsUserAnAdmin` a long time ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Detect if running with elevated privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220213/c-detect-if-running-with-elevated-privileges)

Comment: As far as I know `IsUserAdmin` should no longer be used as it isnt sure if it will be there in the future

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

Comment: Is that enough to cover elevation?  I think for a non-elevated admin that'll return `false`.

Comment: From a quick LinqPad test it looks like I'm right.  I guess technically your code is correct (it'll only return true if you *are* elevated), but that doesn't necessarily mean you *can't* run it.  Bloody UAC :-)

Comment: For a standard user this is returning false.