# Why can .NET app not overwrite file when user is Administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

My WPF app downloads and caches files to the `C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\ProductName\Data\` directory.

If another user was logged in when they downloaded (created) the file, I cannot overwrite the file to update it, even though I am an Administrator.

Why do I not have write access when I am also an Admin user?
The screenshot shows the file permissions of a file I cannot overwrite.

[image: Account Settings]

I understand that I have to elevate the process to do an 'admin' task ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711425)), but seeing as the other user was an Administrator (and so am I), and the 'Owner' of the file is 'Administrator' - why don't I have write permission on a file where the Owner is in the same group? Why don't we share the same privileges?

Comment: That's not how administrative permissions work.  You must request elevation to use administrative privilges, even if you're a member of the administrators group.  See : [Elevation: Accquiring the Admin Token in Administrator vs Standard Accounts in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1083600/388890)

Comment: Related : [What precisely does 'Run as administrator' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8986971/327083)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run as Administrator vs. Administrator group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711425/run-as-administrator-vs-administrator-group)

Answer (score 1):

After downloading and saving the file you may set full access for all users (or any other appropriate group) by code like this:

```
var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(path);

fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule(
        new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null),
        FileSystemRights.FullControl,
        AccessControlType.Allow));

File.SetAccessControl(path, fileSecurity);
```

Comment: Allowing all users to modify a file is a security risk, especially with an application that uses executable files from that directory

Comment: @Ferrybig We're talking about C:\ProgramData, not C:\Programs. OP is asking about some downloaded and cached files, which are supposed to be temporary by nature.

Comment: @Clemens But why if I give permission for a new group 'NewGroup', would all members have write access, if currently all members of group 'Administrators' do not? What is the difference?

Comment: @DefenestrationDay You explicitly set FileSystemRights.FullControl for whatever SecurityIdentifier you like. Take a look at the WellKnownSidType enumeration.