# Detect if running with elevated privileges? (domain administrator accounts included)

Tags: c#, uac, detection, elevated-privileges

Extending this question: [Detect if running as Administrator with or without elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220213/detect-if-running-with-elevated-privileges)

The most voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497572/120591) works if the account to "run as administrator" is a local administrator but if you use a domain administrator account the variable isProcessAdmin returns false. In contrast, UAC accepts the Domain Administrator as a valid account when elevating privileges (create folder in c:\windows\, run as administrator, etc)...How can i modify the UACHelper.IsProcessElevated so it takes into account that case too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the [domain values to IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wd8zba.aspx):

```
// DOMAINNAME\Domain Admins RID: 0x200
bool isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
               || principal.IsInRole(0x200);
```

Comment: i will test this method for the case IsUacEnabled==false and report back, but what about the case IsUacEnabled==true where the line that returns false is this: bool isProcessAdmin = elevationResult == TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeFull;

Comment: with isUacEnabled==false this solution doesnt work. I inspected the variables when doing a run as Administrator with UAC disabled and they are: principal.Identity.AuthenticationType:NTLM, principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated:True, principal.Identity.Name: (the current user that doesnt had admin rights)

Comment: @ase69s: if UAC is disabled...then who cares as there is no concept of "Elevated"?

Comment: doing tests if UAC is disabled it seems that if a normal user runs the program and it tries for example to create a txt in c:\windows\system32\ raises an unauthorizedaccessexception. Strangely, starting it with UAC disabled and "run as administrator" raises the unauthorizedaccessexception too...

Comment: about previous comment it works fine in this case only if i do a Shift + right click -> run as different user -> (using local administrator account or domain administrator account)

Comment: @ase69s: the ACL's on the file likely are the limiting factor with UAC off.

Comment: Yes you are right, then for closuring this topic: could you anwser the question of my first comment? ( what about the case IsUacEnabled==true where the line that returns false is this: bool isProcessAdmin = elevationResult == TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeFull;)

Comment: Perhaps Windows is only asking for limited elevation in that case?