# How to detect if a specific process is elevated using dotnet or powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, process-elevation

How can I detect if a specific process is elevated or not. This process is different than the process where my code is running. I'd like to be able to do this from with PowerShell or C#.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
Get-Process |
Add-Member -Name Elevated -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {if ($this.Name -in @('Idle','System')) {$null} else {-not $this.Path -and -not $this.Handle} } -PassThru |
Format-Table Name,Elevated
```

From http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/03/29/pstip-detecting-if-a-certain-process-is-elevated/

Comment: the above script its great, and works if the process you are running it from is NOT elevated, but if that process itself is elevated its doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, I found that myself when trying to test the code. There are additional properties that cannot be read if you're testing from a non-elevated session. For example, the process Modules property is null (its simpler to check for that instead for Path and handle).

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497572/717732

That `UacHelper` will need some minor changes. Like, `IsProcessElevated` uses `OpenProcessToken` on CurrentProcess - you will need to change the `IsProcessElevated` fo a function and make the `Process` a parameter, so you can inspect any, not just current one.

In general, this class does all that you'd need to. It inspects the security properties assigned to the process. I think that code speaks by itself.

BTW. If you think that code is OK for your needs, please mark your question as 'duplicate' of that one - it will help others in finding that code.